# How do you get original text from etree object

Tags: python, lxml

I'm having trouble finding documentation on this.

I have an object of type `lxml.etree._ElementTree` and am trying to get the original text from it.

The object was generated by executing:

```
tree = etree.parse(content, parser=parser)
```

I then need to access the original content much further along in the script when `content` is no longer available. I would like to get that content by executing some function of `tree` but I can not find any documentation for this.

I'd found reference to a `tostring` function but that seems to be an invalid function.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tostring` is a valid function, perhaps you're using it incorrectly. Here's a fully contained example:

```
from lxml import etree

text = """
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<people>
  <person>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Hal</name>
    <notes>Hal likes chocolate</notes>
  </person>
</people>"""

root = etree.fromstring(text)
etee.tostring(root)
# outputs the following
'<people>\n  <person>\n    <id>1</id>\n    <name>Hal</name>\n    <notes>Hal likes chocolate</notes>\n  </person>\n</people>'
```

Answer (score 4):

[`tostring`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring) is not a method of the tree object, but of the `lxml.etree` library.

So try `lxml.etree.tostring(tree)`.

Note that this may not be EXACTLY the same as the original file - it should parse to the same XML, but spaces, newlines, and other formatting may be different. Also, if you have made any changes to the tree it will not match the original file, obviously.